# Postgres querying json object array

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm working with Postgres 9.5 json arrays. My json object is an array of objects:

```
[{'name' : ... 'field2':...}, {'name' : ...}, {'name', ...}]
```

I'm trying to get all the 'name' values from the array. I can get a specific one with (for example for the first array entry):

```
select jsonarr->0->'name' from items;
```

But I can't get them all and I didn't find a way looking at the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html). I'm searching for something like:

```
select jsonarr->*->'name' from items;
```

how can I do it?

thanks, dan

Comment: `select x->'name' from json_array_elements(jsonarr) t(x);`

Comment: thanks @Abelisto, it worked:

Comment: select x->'name' from items, json_array_elements(jsonarr) t(x);